# In tkinter, why the combination of IntVar/Entry returns a wrong integer when using zero-padding?

Tags: python, tkinter

When using a IntVar to get the content of an Entry widget, the result is wrong when the integer is left zero-padded. For example, if the Entry box contains "05000", the IntVar value is 2560.

This problem can be easily solved by not using the IntVar and recasting the integer directly in python `int(entry.get())`. I am just curious of what is causing this problem; I don't understand exactly which recasting error happens.

Below a toy example reproducing the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

def print_values():
    print("Value 0 - entry: '{}' - integer: {}".format(entry0.get(), int0.get()))
    print("Value 1 - entry: '{}' - integer: {}".format(entry1.get(), int1.get()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    int0 = tk.IntVar(root, 5)
    tk.Label(root, text="Value 0").grid(row=0, column=0)
    entry0 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=int0)
    entry0.insert(0, "0000")
    entry0.grid(row=0, column=1)

    int1 = tk.IntVar(root, 5)
    tk.Label(root, text="Value 1").grid(row=1, column=0)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=int1)
    entry1.insert(0, "0")
    entry1.insert("end", "000")
    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    tk.Button(root, text="Print", command=print_values).grid(row=2, column=1)

    print_values()
    root.mainloop()
```

The value for "00005" is correct while the value for "05000" is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because numbers with leading zeroes are interpreted as octal. So 05000 is 8^3*5. Same happens for me in the interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 05000
2560
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this prefix for octal. It is a little surprising that it happens in python3 where the octal prefix is "0o".

Comment: I agree. But that might be due to the tkinter library being pretty much in low maintenance mode. It might be worth filing a bug, as it IMHO should have changed with the new prefix, too.